# Does Ground Voltage Need Lowered As Well?

Tags: voltage, raspberry-pi, ground

I am dividing voltage of a 9V battery to 3V for a Rasperry Pi GPIO. I have the ground connected to the end of the resistors, so it is back to 9V when I connect it to the Pi's ground pin. Is it ok to have the ground at 9V?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxv1XY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: By definition, "Ground" is zero volts.  Draw a diagram to show us exactly how you have connected and measured things.  This site has a nice schematic editor you can access by hitting "Control-M".

Comment: First time ever drawing a diagram. Let me know if it makes no sense.

Comment: I think I did that wrong. Is that really 3V there or not? I kind of guessed that 3 resistors divides 9V by 3. I was using a multimeter and testing between source power and between each resistor. Is that the right way to measure it? So 3V after first, 6V after second, all 9V after all 3 resistors?

Comment: to get 3v, you should take voltage across R3. @rys

Comment: I hope you are using this 3V just to connect to a GPIO (to indicate that the abttery is present??), not to power the RaPi.

Comment: Yes, just connecting to a GPIO pin. I am actually watching a pin on a DIP that puts out 9V, so I have just been testing using the 9V battery by itself.

Comment: @rys What do you mean by "DIP"?

Comment: Ha, I don't recall :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what I understood from your question is correct, this circuit will help you. It is a voltage divider whose input is 9v and output is 3v (which can be given to your rasperry-pi)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp5EDE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Ok, I must be using my multimeter wrong, so by the time it is at ground it is at 0V?

Comment: Yes ground voltage is 0v. @rys

Comment: Node 3v can be connected to GPIO and the ground pin can be connected to raspberry-pi ground.

Comment: 0V is wherever you want it to be - voltage is relative not absolute. When using a multimeter 0V is where you place your black(-) probe. In many circuits voltages are measured with respect to "ground" but that's not a law just a convention. Sorry if this makes things more complicated but one day you might need to know :)